# How to create a one to many relationship based on one to one (three tables)?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm learning backend development on python, using flask and SQLachemy. I have understood the way to do one-to-one, one-to-many and many-to-many relationships. And now I'm trying to do a more tricky relationship.

There are 3 models class, with these relationships :

- The class A and B have one-to-one relationship
- The class B and C have many(B)-to-one(C) relationship
- The class A and C have many(C)-to-one(A) relationship

And now I want to create a relationship between C and A passing though B relationship (abstract problem formulation, continue the reading for the concrete formulation)

The documentation speaks about `join`, it might be a way to do it, but I'm not able to understand the example
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/join_conditions.html#composite-secondary-joins

```py
from backend import db # db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

```py
class User(db.Model): # class A
    __tablename__ = 'User'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # ...
    albums = db.relationship('Album', backref='auteur')
    # pictures taken as a photograph (pictures_posted may exist, but
    # that's still the same difficulty than with photographer, "circular"
    # relationships
    pictures_taken = db.relationship('Picture', backref='photographe')
```

```py
class Picture(db.Model): # class B
    __tablename__ = 'Picture'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # ...
    album_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Album.id'))
    photographe_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('User.id'))
```

```py
class Album(db.Model): # class C
    __tablename__ = 'Album'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # ...
    pictures = db.relationship('Picture', backref='album')
    auteur_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('User.id'))
```

To be less abstract, I want to access (all) `photographes` who are represented in an `album`, directly from `album`s instances. As i can access to `auteur` and `pictures`.

PS : Should I use polymorphism to handle the problem (sub classes of User : Lambda ; Photographe ; Author) ?

Comment: Hi there, try to be more specific about your problem. Are you getting an error, or unexpected output? For example, check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/5uper5hoot/d5af276712e23306613e3c6f0dc2bbd4). All the relationships seem to be working but maybe I'm missing something. Perhaps use that gist as a starting point for creating an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that produces the exact problem you are experiencing.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your git, i think have badly explained the problem, my purpose is to access album.photographers.all(), i did a gist too
https://gist.github.com/yoann9344/4a6cfaf36eb3dbfd631366ec2589f72b[link]

ps : i adjust the question

Comment: Is this possible? I think the third relationship you put in your post(many C to one A) should not be possible.

Comment: Yeah exactly, that's a copy past error i guess, or i have changed it since i post the question, user_id have to be auteur_id. I change this :] edit : same mistake in Picture ><"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the most convenient answer is to use a property inside Album's class.

```py
class Album(db.Model):
    # ...
    @property
    def photographes(self):
        photographes = set()
        for img in self.pictures:
            if img.photographe not in photographes:
                photographes.add(img.photographe)
        return photographes
```

I have shared whole my backend on [git](https://github.com/yoann9344/flask-sqlalchemy-example), it could be useful !

Comment: @yoannquillard , I made some changes in my answer. I hope that the answer is now ok and do the same as your (@)property but in one line of code.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/9205369/matija-lukic Stil not this, you are calling the pictures of the author made as a photographe ! So i realize there are still ambiguous names ! i edit this

Answer (score 0):

If you want reverse access (from albums to author's all images):

```
album = Album.query.filter_by(id=111).first()
```

then:

```
images = album.auteur.images
```

Comment: My variables' names are a bit confusing, there are photographe (photographer) and photographie (picture). I edit my code to be more comprehensible  !

Comment: You wrote 'I want to access (all) photographs who are represented in an album'. You mean 'which are represented in an album'? Do you want photos or photographers related to an album? Words that you use is so confusing, I suggest you to use only English words.

Comment: I mean who, the guy who took the picture, the photographer. That's a bit confusing cause I wrote class names in French and I have chosen confusing words. A `Picture` got an `user` who did the picture called `photographe`

Comment: Matija Lukic, yes I agree with it, but I wanna call the photographers not the author of the album, for that I need to add another relationship between picture and album which calls photographer